# Flatten inner tuples inside 3D NumPy array and save to CSV as floats

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, flatten

I would like to flatten the innermost and outermost axes of a 3(/4) dimensional NumPy array, when the innermost rows contain mixed-type entries: both floats and arrays/tuples of floats. I would then like to save this to a CSV file with all values as type float64.

```
have = [[[0.0 array([24.0,25.0]) 2.0 3.0]
         [4.0 array([26.0,27.0]) 6.0 7.0]
         [8.0 array([28.0,29.0]) 10.0 11.0]]

        [[12.0 array([30.0,31.0]) 14.0 15.0]
         [16.0 array([30.0,31.0]) 18.0 19.0]
         [20.0 array([30.0,31.0]) 22.0 23.0]]]

target = [[0.0 24.0 25.0 2.0 3.0]
              [4.0 26.0 27.0 6.0 7.0]
              [8.0 28.0 29.0 10.0 11.0]
              [12.0 30.0 31.0 14.0 15.0]
              [16.0 30.0 31.0 18.0 19.0]
              [20.0 30.0 31.0 22.0 23.0]]

np.savetxt('target.csv', target, delimiter=',')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question uses the example of a 3D array with an array element pointer at a central index, however the existing answers do not directly apply to your example input/output without further nontrivial steps. Here is a solution which achieves everything you have asked for (and will generalise) from your example to the CSV file in an efficient and concise way.

First let's create your example array `have`.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> have = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4).astype('object')
>>> ins = np.arange(24,36)
>>> c = 0
>>> for i in range(2):
        for j in range(3):
            have[i][j][1] = np.array([ins[c], ins[c+1]])
            c += 2
>>> print(have)                                      # The exact array as in the question.
[[[0 array([24, 25]) 2 3]
  [4 array([26, 27]) 6 7]
  [8 array([28, 29]) 10 11]]

 [[12 array([30, 31]) 14 15]
  [16 array([32, 33]) 18 19]
  [20 array([34, 35]) 22 23]]]
```

Now we will create a new array to become your `target` array.

```
# Axis 1 is not needed as output will be all rows
#
all_rows          = np.vstack(have)
# Efficiently create dummy array of correct size
#                              
>>> target        = np.empty((have.shape[0]*have.shape[1], 4+1))
# LHS floats in correct positions
#
>>> target[:,:1]  = all_rows[:,:1]
# RHS floats in correct positions
#                             
>>> target[:,-2:] = all_rows[:,-2:]
# Slicing at a single index converts each array to floats
#
>>> target[:,1:3] = np.vstack(all_rows[:,1])    
>>> print(target)                                    # The exact array as in the question.
[[ 0. 24. 25.  2.  3.]
 [ 4. 26. 27.  6.  7.]
 [ 8. 28. 29. 10. 11.]
 [12. 30. 31. 14. 15.]
 [16. 32. 33. 18. 19.]
 [20. 34. 35. 22. 23.]]
```

This results in an array `target` with all entries of type `float64` and so we can save to a CSV file in the current directory exactly as you have suggested in your question.

```
>>> np.savetxt('target.csv', target, delimiter=',')
```

Also just to let you know, you can include inline code/highlights on Stack Overflow using single 'backticks' instead of the normal single quotation mark used in your question. This is often found immediately below the `Esc` key on a keyboard.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. I wish I could reward this answer with a bounty. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

When you display `have` numpy only knows that it has a (2,4) array in which some of the entries are pointers to other objects (numpy doesn't know what those are, but accesses their displays when you print `have`). As such, any solution is going to require gathering up these other arrays to re-assign them elsewhere, since numpy is not going to know in advance that all the arrays are the same size.

```
import numpy as np

have         = np.array([[np.array([1,2]),5],[np.array([3,4]),7]])
target       = np.empty((2,3))      #Create some empty space
target[:,2]  = have[:,1]            #Reassign all the float points to their locations
target[:,:2] = np.vstack(have[:,0]) #Stack all the other arrays (assumes same size)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for the specific scenario in the question.

1. access the inner most array
2. check the instance of each element
3. if it is of type `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` call `.tolist()` to convert it to *python list* and use `+` operator merge the list to the existing inner list

**Code:**

```py
import numpy as np
have = [
    [
        [0.0, np.array([24.0,25.0]), 2.0, 3.0],
         [4.0, np.array([26.0,27.0]), 6.0, 7.0],
         [8.0, np.array([28.0,29.0]), 10.0, 11.0]
    ],

    [
        [12.0, np.array([30.0,31.0]), 14.0, 15.0],
         [16.0, np.array([30.0,31.0]), 18.0, 19.0],
         [20.0, np.array([30.0,31.0]), 22.0, 23.0]
    ]
]

tar = []
for i, e1 in enumerate(have):
    tar.append([])
    for j, e2 in enumerate(e1):
        temp = []
        for e3 in e2:
            if isinstance(e3, np.ndarray):
                temp += e3.tolist()
            else:
                temp.append(e3)
        tar[i].append(temp)

print(tar)
```

**Ouptut:**

```
[[[0.0, 24.0, 25.0, 2.0, 3.0],
 [4.0, 26.0, 27.0, 6.0, 7.0],
 [8.0, 28.0, 29.0, 10.0, 11.0]],

[[12.0, 30.0, 31.0, 14.0, 15.0],
 [16.0, 30.0, 31.0, 18.0, 19.0], 
[20.0, 30.0, 31.0, 22.0, 23.0]]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It  is a little complicated and your Axis 1 is not in my target array. For the millions of rows I mentioned in the question, the 'for' loops are slow. But thank you anyway, I have learned about the .tolist method as a bonus.

Comment: @SO1999 yes I agree  this method might be slower. Apart from that the output has the same structure as the target array you provided in the question. I didn't understand what you meant by that part.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's fair to say that the core of your problem is merging numpy.ndarrays into existing lists of floats, rather than manipulations of the outer dimensions of the lists. The piece of code below addresses that problem, using your first inner list as an example:

```
import numpy as np

iList = [0.0, np.array([24.0,25.0]), 2.0, 3.0]

newList = []
for i in iList:
    if type(i) == np.ndarray:
        lList = i.tolist()
        for l in lList:
            newList.append(l)
    else:
        newList.append(i)
```

If you run this test code you can confirm that all the results are now floats:

```
for x in newList:
    print(type(x))
```

which outputs:

```
<class 'float'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'float'>
```

Saving to CSV is well-covered elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This works on one row of one subarray of the overall array -- would it be efficient on a large scale (say >1M rows) to use two 'for' loops to apply this to each sub-sub array?

Comment: @SO1999, sorry, I'm not sure on that one. If you're doing something like that on a large scale, and you have multiple methods for the outer loop(s), it's probably worth trying them both and comparing the runtime using the "timeit" module.

Comment: I have compared the times for the different responses on 1 million rows and the 'for' loops are much slower than the accepted answer. Thank you for response though, I have learned about the .tolist method as a bonus